# System not mounting as rw

Tags: root-access, system

I wanted to copy an app to the system folder so I tried it using es file explorer but it said read-only so I looked up online and tried mounting it using this command `mount -o rw,remount /system`  but got this error, what should I do? btw I am using a rooted oneplus 7 with magisk

```
:/ $ su
:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts
1|:/ #
```

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220370
https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220892
https://android.stackexchange.com/q/223872

Comment: If you have magisk than don't bother with modifying your system partition. Try App Systemizer Magisk module. Easiest solution I see to make an app a system app.

Comment: Thanks for the help I tried doing it but it didn't seem to work so I downgraded to android 9 and rooted again it seems to work perfectly now and android 10 sucks for rooting.